# Inheriting methods that run a non-reentrant critical section

Tags: python, decorator

I have a Python program with multiple threads that manipulate a shared resource. I model this resource with an object and actions on this resource with methods in that object. A number of actions need to be performed as atomic actions, in a critical section. Since these functions follow a common pattern, I used a decorator:

```
def critical_section(inner):
    def outer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.enter()
        inner(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.leave()
    return outer
```

The real code is more complex than this, e.g. it handles exceptions, but this should be enough to get the gist of what I'm doing. Sample usage (I simplified all the thread-related stuff and just check for resource ownership):

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.owner = None
    def enter(self):
        assert(self.owner == None)
        self.owner = True
    def leave(self):
        assert(self.owner == True)
        self.owner = None
    @critical_section
    def foo(self):
        print('foo') # Dangerous stuff, must run atomically and not fail
```

Functions with the `critical_section` decorator have two properties:

- The function's code is executed with the resource's lock held (`enter` and `leave` take care of that).
- The function assumes that the resource is in a stable state on entry, and leaves it in a stable state on exit.

The second property implies that the lock is not a reentrant one. It is invalid to call a “critical section” function while already in a critical section, because the necessary invariants are not guaranteed.

The implementation of `enter` and `leave` check these properties: a thread can't call `enter` if the resource is currently owned (even by that thread itself), and `enter` gives ownership of the resource to the calling thread; `leave` symmetrically requires ownership and gives it up.

That architecture served me nicely until I wanted to have multiple resources with a similar structure, so I started to use inheritance.

```
class Derived(Base):
    @critical_section
    def foo(self):
        print('fie') # Additional stuff to run first
        Base.foo(self)
```

And now we come to the problem: that decorator is fundamentally inheritance-unfriendly.

```
base = Base()
base.foo()
derived = Derived()
derived.foo()
```

The call to `derived.foo()` fails because when `Base.foo()` is executed, the resource is already owned. At the point where the base class's method is called, the derived class has potentially already mucked up the object, violating the assumption that `Base.foo` starts with an object in known stable state.

The obvious solution would be to turn every critical-section function into a pair of functions: the outer function (meant to be called from outside, and never overridden in classes that modify the behavior of the resource), and the inner function (meant to be called only from derived methods).

1. Can Python decorators help me define such pairs of functions with a minimum of boilerplate?
2. Is there a better architecture that would maximize the clarity of where critical sections are entered and exited from, and minimize the risk of misuse? (Dynamic checks are good, but obvious correctness of source code is better.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello, me from yesterday. Your fundamental problem is that you oversimplified the situation. You conflated two things: entering/leaving the critical section, and assuming/asserting the resource's invariants. But the resource's invariants can also be true in the middle of the critical section, and that's precisely what you're trying to convey when you say that `Derived.foo` method is allowed to call `Base.foo` (at some particular point during this execution).

You can model this in Python, but it does get a bit cumbersome.

```
def critical_section(inner):
    def outer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.enter()
        inner(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.leave()
    return outer

class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.owner = None
        self.invariants = True
    def enter(self):
        assert(self.invariants)
        self.invariants = False
        assert(self.owner == None)
        self.owner = True
    def leave(self):
        assert(self.owner == True)
        self.owner = None
        self.invariants = True
    @critical_section
    def foo(self):
        print('foo') # Dangerous stuff, must run atomically and not fail
class Derived(Base):
    @critical_section
    def foo(self):
        print('fie') # Additional stuff to run first
        self.invariants = True
        Base.foo(self)
```

The owner stuff should be a reentrant lock in the real world. Instead of having non-reentrancy to prevent modifying the resource while it's in an unstable state, there's this invariants check.

But all this is complicated and not really worth it when “checking invariants” amounts to “I state that the useful invariants are verified at this point in the code”. With invariants checked by static analysis, it would be another story, but then you wouldn't be using Python.

---

Coming back to your question, which was accessing the inner function when needed, Python does make it pretty easy. Store the inner function in an attribute of the decorated function.

```
def critical_section(inner):
    def outer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.enter()
        inner(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.leave()
    outer.inner_function = inner
    return outer
…
class Derived(Base):
    @critical_section
    def foo(self):
        print('fie') # Additional stuff to run first
        Base.inner.foo(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Here's a proper non-reentrant version.

You can have decorators take in arguments. so `@dec(x); def f() ...` will be called like `dec(x)(f)(args)`. So, we have `critical_section` take in a string (`@critical_section("Base")`) and have one lock per string.

```
def critical_section(ident):
    def _critical_section(inner):
        def outer(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.enter(ident)
            inner(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.leave(ident)
        return outer
    return _critical_section

class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.owner = {}
    def enter(self, ident):
        assert(ident not in self.owner)
        self.owner[ident] = True
    def leave(self, ident):
        assert(ident in self.owner)
        del self.owner[ident]
    @critical_section("Base")
    def foo(self):
        print('foo') # Dangerous stuff, must run atomically and not fail

class Derived(Base):
    @critical_section("Derived")
    def foo(self):
        print('fie') # Additional stuff to run first
        Base.foo(self)
```

Comment: As I explain in my question, when I invoke `enter` from inside the class, that's usually an error, indicating that I'm relying on invariants that are currently not guaranteed. I initially used a `threading.RLock` and moved away from that because it wasn't detecting programming errors in my resource implementation. I'm trying to get “non-reentrant except when explicitly allowed” rather than “reentrant except when explicitly forbidden”.

Comment: I've edited my reply to to be non-reentrant. The lock can only be grabbed once per class.